# Series with recursive terms: reciprocal of the sums of previous terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

What are some references and material that are devoted to studying series of the form

$x_1+\frac1{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_1+\frac1{x_1}}+\dotsc$
where $x_1>0$ is given?

For instance, my (non math) friend just wrote down (somewhat as a "joke")
the series

$(1+1/2)+\frac1{1+1/2}+\frac{1}{1+1/2+\frac1{1+1/2}}+\dotsc$

and I am honestly baffled by it. (They actually wrote down
$$\frac{1}{(1+1/2)+\frac1{1+1/2}+\frac{1}{1+1/2+\frac1{1+1/2}}+\dotsc}$$
but I figured I would just study the series itself. But would this be related to continued fractions? It doesn't look quite the same in form.)

How would one study the convergence or divergence of the given series (or series of the same form)? I've only encountered sequences defined recursively, say the one to approximate $\sqrt{x}$, or $\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p+\dotsc}}$, or $\sqrt{2}^{{\sqrt{2}}^{\dotsc}}$ and these are relatively easy to handle.

I've tried to study the $n$-th term $x_n=\frac{1}{x_1+x_2+\dotsc+x_{n-1}}$ where $x_1=(1+1/2)$ and the partial sums $s_n=x_1+\dotsc+x_n$ to see if I could say *something* about the convergence of the sequence $(x_n)$ or $(s_n)$ but the recurrence relation makes it too messy for me to see anything clearly about their behaviors. Thanks in advance for looking at this (and I really hope I'm not missing something obvious here...)

(While writing this question [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675178/recursive-sum-of-previous-term-and-its-inverse) popped up as related and it has the (edit!) same recurrence  .)

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is your recurrence relation different from the other one? I get the exactly the same series from it. Of course, the other thread has no answer either.

Comment: Ah! You're right, i should have inspected it more. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the sequence satisfies the recurrence relation $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac1{x_n} = \frac{x_n^2 + 1}{x_n}$ or $x_{n+1}x_n = x_n^2 + 1$. So if it converges, the limit $x$ must satisfy $$x^2 = x^2 + 1$$ which cannot be. Therefore the sequence cannot converge.

Note that the sequence is always positive, so $1/x_n > 0$ and $x_{n+1} > x_n$, so the sequence is increasing. Increasing + doesn't converge $\implies$ diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But actually, I take back my initial comment; I think the sequences are different. My first few terms are 
$x_1, \frac{1}{x_1}, \frac{1}{x_1+\frac{1}{x_1}},\dotsc$
and the other sequence has,
$x_1, x_1+\frac{1}{x_1},  x_1+\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{ x_1+\frac{1}{x_1}},\dotsc$. It is a very slight difference, no? In fact isn't the latter sequence the sequence of partial sums of my sequence? So your proof applies to this latter sequence and answers the question of convergence of the series, which thank you again, it is nice. Please correct me if this is mistaken!

Comment: Ah! (After investigating more) my sequence satisfies the inverse of the recurrence relation you gave, so it can be seen that the sequence converges to $0$, but the series it forms diverges as you showed. Thank you again! I'll accept this answer.